# How to use Dissmissible with ReorderableListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I am trying to use ReorderableListView with Dissmissable Feature. Data is grabbed from API in the form of a list. Dissmissible feature isn't working in code below.

Note: The below code works properly when I use Listview.builder instead.

```
ReorderableListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        if (oldIndex != newIndex) {
           //reorder action 
        },
        itemCount: list.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Dismissible(
            direction: DismissDirection.up,
            onDismissed: (direction) {},
            key: UniqueKey(),
            child: ReorderableDragStartListener(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              index: index,
              child: SizedOverflowBox(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                size: const Size(50, 10),
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/${list[index]}.png"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The error here was initially that you cannot swipe to dismiss because the ReorderableDragStartListener would not allow dismissible to dismiss it.

One best solution is to have a mechanism to switch between reordering and dismissing.

Here is one solution I came up with :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<String> list = ["1", "2", "3"];

  bool reorder;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    reorder = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          label: reorder ? const Text("Done") : const Text("Reorder"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              reorder = !reorder;
            });
          }),
      body: reorder
          ? ReorderableListView.builder(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                if (newIndex >= list.length) return;
                print(oldIndex);
                print(newIndex);
                setState(() {
                  var tmp = list[oldIndex];
                  list[oldIndex] = list[newIndex];
                  list[newIndex] = tmp;
                  print(list);
                });
              },
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ReorderableDragStartListener(
                  index: index,
                  key: ValueKey(index),
                  child: ListTile(title: Text("${list[index]}")),
                );
              },
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (c, i) {
                return Dismissible(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  background: Container(color: Colors.red),
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    setState(() {
                      list.removeAt(i);
                    });
                  },
                  child: ListTile(title: Text("${list[i]}")),
                );
              }),
    );
  }
}
```

Here, we are simply using `reorder` variable to switch the modes

Comment: Problem is same even withou ReorderableDragStartListener.
Okay i will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to use custom ReorderableDragStartListener. You can configure it to start only vertical drag while Dismissible works in horizontal dimentions. In this way

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [ReorderableListView].

void main() => runApp(const ReorderableApp());

class ReorderableApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReorderableApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('ReorderableListView Sample')),
        body: const ReorderableExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ReorderableExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReorderableExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<ReorderableExample> createState() => _ReorderableListViewExampleState();
}

class _ReorderableListViewExampleState extends State<ReorderableExample> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(50, (int index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    final Color oddItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.05);
    final Color evenItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.15);

    return ReorderableListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
      buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index += 1)
        Dismissible(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
            onDismissed: (direction) {},
            child: ListTile(
            tileColor: _items[index].isOdd ? oddItemColor : evenItemColor,
            title: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
            trailing: _VerticalDragStartListener(
                  index: index,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.drag_handle),
                ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }
          final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
          _items.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}

class _VerticalDragStartListener extends ReorderableDragStartListener {
  const _VerticalDragStartListener({
    required super.child,
    required super.index,
  });

  @override
  MultiDragGestureRecognizer createRecognizer() {
    return VerticalMultiDragGestureRecognizer(debugOwner: this);
  }
}
```